# I imported a type library ( .tlb ) into Delphi and a function parameter seems incorrect. How should I fix it?

Tags: c++, delphi, idl

I've used midl to convert a .idl file to a .tlb. When I import this .tlb file into Delphi (XE7), it converts this Write function which is part of

```
interface IWTSVirtualChannel : IUnknown
...

HRESULT Write(
    [in]            ULONG               cbSize,
    [in, size_is(cbSize)] BYTE          *pBuffer,
    [in]            IUnknown            *pReserved          // must be NULL
    );
```

into this Delphi code in the _TLB.pas file.

```
function Write(
 cbSize: LongWord; 
 var pBuffer: Byte; 
 const pReserved: IUnknown): HResult; stdcall;
```

However the 2nd parameter is clearly incorrect. To my mind it should be something like

```
 pBuffer : PAnsiChar;
```

The parameter is a c-type string, passed into the Write to send.

So it seems to me that I should just edit the _TLB.pas file and fix it. There's a couple of other procedures that also have this problem.

But I'm reluctant, as I'd have to redo the edit any time I changed the .idl (hopefully not too often; with the associated hassle of unregistering the .tlb type library before re-importing it) but it doesn't seem right and yet I'm fairly certain that it will not work as is.

What's the best thing I should do? Sticking with C++ is not an option!

Comment: "To my mind it should be PAnsiChar" => Wrong.

COM types are almost always using some types that the framework already knows how to marshal, i.e. BYTE* , BSTR, SAFEARRAY etc. Strings are almost always wid and never plain pointers. (Stick with C++).

Comment: As I understand it a pAnsiChar is effectively a typedef (the Delphi equivalent) for  byte *.

Comment: Okay,then what's the problem with the automatically generated source?

Comment: In C/C++ pBuffer is a pointer. In Delphi, it's a byte. The var means that if the value is changed inside the function, it updates the external byte (pass by reference). But it certainly wouldn't let me pass in a c-String.

Comment: pAnsiChar sounds good to me. In some Delphi versions there's also PByteArray, which seems slightly closer to the intent expressed in the h file, IMO. As for your comment about having to redo this change, why would you ever re-run midl on the same idl, once it works?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this and had practised with two other idl files. I found that the dlldata.c file that midl generates included the two other type libraries. So I moved the .idl and associated files (it's tsvirtualchannels.idl btw) and winapifamily.h ) into a folder on their own, unregistered the imported tlb file and reimported it.

Comment: `"As I understand it a pAnsiChar is effectively a typedef (the Delphi equivalent) for byte *."` The Delphi equivalent is *PByte*. If it had to be *PAnsiChar*, it should have been coded as `char *`.

Comment: FWIW, the description of Write says: "A pointer to a buffer on the channel to which to write the data. You can reuse this buffer as soon as the call returns.". ISTM that you are meant to write bytes, not text. The bytes may contain text, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to an array of bytes whose size is provided in the first argument. The correct translation of the second argument is

```
pBuffer: PByte
```

Comment: Assuming it is the TLB importer in the IDE that did the conversion, obviously that importer needs some work. It should not declare as `var byte` what should be converted as `PByte` (which the `size_is` clearly indicates). This should be reported at Quality Portal.

Comment: Rudy. You possibly have the .idl file on a PC. It's tsvirtualchannels.idl. On my PC it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um . Perhaps you could see if a version of Delphi later than XE7 still does this?

Comment: @DavidBolton: I do have the file here. It can even be found in the RAD Studio distribution, but also in the directory you mentioned (x.x.17763.0/um). But you'd have to guide me setting up cl.exe and midl.exe. I have only used cl.exe a few times, for single files, and probably not with the proper setup. MIDL complains it needs cl.exe. Anyway, it is late now, so not before tomorrow.

Comment: @RudyVelthius copy the tsvirtualchannels.lib file and winapifamily.h (should be in that ..\um folder) into a folder of their own. From the command line in that folder do midl tsvirtualchannels.idl /tlb tsvirtualchannels.tlb